# Sum up all the integers in range()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that sums up all the integers which can be divided by 3 in the range of 100 to 2000. I'm not even sure where to start, so far I've got this tiny piece of code written which isn't correct.

```
for x in range(100, 2001, 3):
      print(x+x)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In case this is more like "invent an algorithm" homework, a hint might be enough: a number is divisible by three in case the individual compontents sum up to a number divisible by three (e.g. 948 is divisible by three because 9+4+8 = 21 which is divisible by three and so on and so forth).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use generator expression and sum function here:

```
res = sum(x for x in range(100, 2001) if x % 3 == 0)
```

It's pretty self-explanatory code: you're summing all the numbers from 100 to 2000, inclusive, which are divisible by three.

Comment: You can remove the `[]` - no need to materialize the list just to calculate the sum.

Comment: @ThiefMaster if it doesn't materialize the list, what value does it pass to sum?

Comment: @JesseRusak `sum` operates over iterables, so will consume items from the generator...

Answer (score 20):

Since you know the first number in this range that is divisible by 3 is 102, you can do the following:

**Solution:**

```
>>> sum(range(102, 2001, 3))
664650
```

**To make it into a robust function:**

```
def sum_range_divisible(start, end, divisor):
    while start % divisor != 0:
        start += 1
    return sum(range(start, end, divisor))
```

**Using it:**

```
>>> sum_range_divisible(100, 2001, 3)
664650
```

**Note:**

The advantage here is that you do not have to check each number in the whole range, since you are jumping by 3 each time.

---

**Timing:**

I have timed the different solutions, mine and [aga's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20456023/1561176):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('sum(range(102, 2001, 3))').repeat()
[9.516391893850312, 9.49330620765817, 9.508695564438462]
>>> timeit.Timer('sum(x for x in range(100, 2001) if x % 3 == 0)').repeat()
[134.757627812011, 134.46399066622394, 138.34528734198346]
```

**Conclusion:**

My answer is faster by a factor of **14**

Comment: Not that it matters with `3`, but `while start % divisor != 0: start += 1` isn't great for large `divisor`. Maybe `start += (-start % abs(divisor))`.

Comment: @InbarRose no need to time my solution and yours - it's obvious that plain summing of numbers is a lot more faster than traversing the range which is three times longer than yours, filtering only those numbers which can be divided by three w/o the remainder and summing them. :) you've come up with an elegant solution, +1 for this.

Comment: @InbarRose I like your solution, but aga's solution includes a loop which I was meant to use.

Comment: @maku You are of course free to make your own choices, but being "meant" to use something sounds like this was an assignment, if it was - you should have included that as part of your question, regardless - I hope you realize that you have chosen not to take the optimal solution.

Answer (score 11):

There is a closed formula for that.

If (u_i) is a sequence defined by its first term u_0 and its common difference r, then the sum of the n first terms of (u_i) is:

[image: \frac{n(u_0 + u_{n-1})}{2}]

EDIT: I have made this little [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kN4p7MGNlQ) to explain it visually.

A [popular anecdote](https://brilliant.org/wiki/gauss-the-prince-of-mathematics/) attributes this formula to the young Johann Carl Friedrich Gauss.

In your case:

- u_0 = 102
- u_{n-1} = 1998
- n = (1998 - 102) / 3 + 1 = 633

So, the sum is (633 * (102 + 1998)) / 2 = 664650.

As a general Python function with the usual `range` arguments `start`, `stop`, `step`:

```
def arithmetic_series(start, stop, step):
    number_of_terms = (stop - start) // step
    sum_of_extrema = start + (stop - step)
    return number_of_terms * sum_of_extrema // 2
```

In your case, the call would be:

```
arithmetic_series(102, 2001, 3)
```

The complexity is O(1) instead of O(n), so unsurprisingly:

```
%timeit sum(range(102, 2001, 3))
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.7 µs per loop

%timeit arithmetic_series(102, 2001, 3)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 548 ns per loop
```

Comment: Outsmarted with math, I like it! Much like mCoding suggests, [source](https://youtu.be/Qgevy75co8c)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [sum function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

```
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, range(100, 2000)))
664650
```

But this is better:

```
>>> sum(x for x in range(100, 2000) if x % 3 == 0)
664650
```

Comment: Wrong, because you are summing numbers no divisible by 3.

Comment: Actually it isn't wrong, because there is a such function. but I'll edit the post, thanks, my bad

Comment: Please don't use lambda filters. It's better to use a list comprehension / generator expression instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(filter(lambda l : l%3 ==0, range(100,2001)))
```

Comment: Please don't use lambda filters. It's better to use a list comprehension / generator expression instead.

Comment: I don't think we should  discuss new chapter of lambda here, for some reasons I use them, there is already a great discussion  regarding lambda . In short, please go to this link https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/060415.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it in Recursive way .

Utilizing a range_sum function

```
def range_sum(array):
if array[0]==array[1]:
    return array[0]
else:
    return range_sum([array[0],array[1]-1])+array[1]
range=[1,4]
print(range_sum(range))
```

> 10