# how to print only the total after computing?

Tags: python, loops, sum

I'm trying to write a code that would add the total of all the values from 0 to 100 and printing only the total after computing with any loop structure.

For another one I did it was short so I did this

```
def listsum(numList):
    iSum = 0
    for i in numList:
        iSum = iSum + i
    return iSum

print(listsum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

but 0 to 100 is too much ,, is there another way?

Comment: [This could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455977/sum-up-all-the-integers-in-range)

Answer (score 1):

Use a range:

```
print(listsum(list(range(101))))
```

Comment: @JeffUK no, I mean exactly what it says - i.e. call the listsum function (defined by the poster) with a list composed of all integers from 0 to 100.

Comment: @JeffUK. Indeed you could, but the question was about passing a list to the poster-defined listsum function.

Answer (score 0):

Using [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
def listsum(numList):
    iSum = 0
    for i in range(1, numList+1):
        iSum += i
    return iSum
```

You would just pass the max value that you want the count up to (e.g. `print(listsum(100))`).

Answer (score 0):

The built-in sum() function gives the total value of all numbers in a list, so your listsum() function is not needed.

`list(range(101))` gives you a list of all numbers from 1-100 (inclusive)

Putting those together you get

```
print(sum(list(range(101))))
```

Which adds the total of all the values from 0 to 100

The range function is much more powerful than this, [here's a good reference for using it](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) it's something you really need to know how to use well!